# is there a quick method to return saved data to its default value in mongoose.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my User Schema I have various fields with various default values.  By example, see a few fields below:

```
acceptedStatus: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    default: 'no' //possibilities (no, yes, thinkingAboutIt, yesInFuture)
}
```

Is there a way to quickly return the saved data for a particular field to its default value without explicitly doing it like

```
    user.acceptedStatus = 'no';
```

and, if so, is there a way to return all fields that carry default values to their original status.  Thanks for your help. There are times when I need to quickly do this, and didn't know if there were any methods I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be that you store schema in an object, then from that object you can easily come to know what property have defaults.

Comment: Sorry. Had a death in the family and my week went to heck.  Thanks for the answer.  I am using it today.  And it does work.  I guess I was just hoping for a quick method, like user.acceptedStatus.returnToDefault() or something that I missed in the docs.  If no other answers post something like that which works, I will mark yours as the accepted